# set Z index not working. button behind a container (HTML - CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-metro, metro-ui-css

I using Metro css (windows 8 style) and have a problem.
I have container with alerts (the blue in the picture) ,
and above , there is 'IT -CENTER ' , If I click there it open a button.
the problem that the button behind the container..
I try to set the Z index of the container to -1 , and it's not help.
[image]

the dropdownlist with the button(IT-CENTER):
    
                   
                     IT-CENTER

```
              <li style="z-index:3"><a href="Login.aspx">התנתק</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

and the container(blue one):

```
 <div id="alerts-container" style="z-index:-1">
         <div id="toast-example1" class="toast toasttext02 fade in">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
            <div class="pull-left">
               <div class="toast-object icon-info-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="toast-body" style="text-align:right">
```

(it's without  the closing tags..)

what should I do?

thanks!!

Comment: A common mistake is that people assume `z-index` is global, it's not, it's relative. Can you show your full code in a jsFiddle or comparable so we can tinker?

Comment: do this:
 `style="z-index:-1; position:relative;"`

Comment: with relative the container dissappear

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. You must set `position:relative` if you are setting `z-index` - it is very important thing and can lead to your bug
2. If the 1 method doesn't help you should try to set `z-index`es to the possible parents of that button (can say for sure I don't see your code)

Answer (score 2):

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to parent DIV worked for me

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.