# Close popover on eventClick function fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Hi i'm using the last version of fullcalendar and i want close this popover:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover
When i'm call the eventClick function:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

Comment: There's nothing in the fullCalendar API which enables that to happen. Why is it a problem if the popover stays open?

Comment: I'm just open a modal in front of the popover and he stay here so we can open the modal so much time :D and we don't see all my modal with the popover

Comment: Surely if you just give your modal a higher z-index there will be no problem

Comment: Yes nice idea that's s great

Comment: See this link in my case for angularjs component with $uibModal
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207239/15833848